# Pad a string with leading zeros, not working for 1 character incoming string.

Tags: sql-server, string, t-sql

I am trying to pad the front of a string with leading zeros so it is 8 characters long. I've written this little thing:

```
DECLARE @pn VARCHAR(8) = '123'
SELECT RIGHT(REPLICATE('0', 8 - LEN(@pn)) + @pn, @pn)
```

It works fine, except if the length of the string is only one character long, or if the string has no characters in it. I think I sort of expect it to happen if the length of the string is 0, but can't exactly explain why. However, I don't know why it doesn't work if the incoming string is 1 character. So am looking for some help on how to deal with a 1 character incoming string?

Thanks!

Comment: `RIGHT(REPLICATE('0', 8) + @pn, 8)`. I don't know why you think passing `@pn` as the second argument to `RIGHT` makes sense, but it decidedly does not.

Comment: Sorry, I am trying to learn this stuff, and I guess somewhere along the way of playing with this, I got myself slightly confused about what the different parameters were and didn't quite pick up on the mistake I had made.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If 2012+, you can use **Format()**

Great functionalitly, but not known to be a high performer.

Also assuming @pn is numerics only (no alpha).

**Example**

```
DECLARE @pn VARCHAR(8) = '123'
SELECT format(0+@pn,'00000000')
```

**Returns**

```
00000123
```

Comment: Thank you, I have used format, because when I came to using this on the actual table I was selecting from, rather than a variable, the data type was one that format would handle, but the other solutions didn't.

Answer (score 1):

You are using @pn as cut length for RIGHT()

```
DECLARE @pn VARCHAR(8) = '123'
SELECT RIGHT(REPLICATE('0', 8 - LEN(@pn)) + @pn, 8)
```

and to go further, if you are using RIGHT(), calculating length on @pn is not needed:

```
SELECT RIGHT(REPLICATE('0', 8) + @pn, 8)
```

or even

```
SELECT RIGHT('000000000' + @pn, 8)
```

Comment: Brilliant, thank you for this, I tried this solution as well. The only reason the other was marked as accepted was because that was the one that I have ended up using, and the data type on the table I was using in the end didn't work with this solution, but I am now doing a similar thing somewhere else. Thanks for the advice and explanation

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it looks like the main issue is using @pn as a parameter to RIGHT.

Also to add to John's explanation, I would toss in a LTRIM or if @pn has a preceding space it will be added to either solution.

So 
Select Right(Replicate('0',8) + LTRIM(@pn),8)

Something to be aware of with the Len() Function:  Len behaves as if it has an implicit RTRIM built in

```
DECLARE @d Char(8) = '1    '   
 select len (@d)               -- Will return 1
 Select @d = '   1'
 select len (@d)               -- Will Return 4
```

Comment: Brilliant, thank you for the explanation. I sometimes get my self confused with manipulating strings.. I am still fairly new to SQL :)